# Create an Array of Strings in Node from a URL

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to take the txt contents of this URL:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/monosans/proxy-list/main/proxies/http.txt

And create an array named httpProxies where each line from the URL represents a value in the array.

Basically I want:

```
console.log(httpProxies); //to return [ '78.110.195.242:7080', '144.86.187.56:8888', '64.225.4.85:9999', '34.146.64.228:3128', ...]
```

I began using this code:

```
const getScript = (url) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const http      = require('http'),
          https     = require('https');

    let client = http;

    if (url.toString().indexOf("https") === 0) {
        client = https;
    }

    client.get(url, (resp) => {
        let data = '';

        // A chunk of data has been recieved.
        resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
            data += chunk;
        });

        // The whole response has been received. Print out the result.
        resp.on('end', () => {
            resolve(data);
        });

    }).on("error", (err) => {
        reject(err);
    });
});
};

(async (url) => {
    console.log(await getScript(url));
})('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/monosans/proxy-list/main/proxies/http.txt');
```

But I am unsure how to create the array. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
const getScript = async(url) => {
  const responce = await fetch(url);
  const data = await responce.text();
  return data.split("\n");
};

(async() => {
  const httpProxies = await getScript(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/monosans/proxy-list/main/proxies/http.txt"
  );
  console.log(httpProxies);
})();
```

---

And if you want to know how to do it with your code then just do this `resolve(data.split('\n'));`

```js
const getScript = (url) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const http = require('http'),
      https = require('https');

    let client = http;

    if (url.toString().indexOf('https') === 0) {
      client = https;
    }

    client
      .get(url, (resp) => {
        let data = '';

        // A chunk of data has been recieved.
        resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
          data += chunk;
        });

        // The whole response has been received. Print out the result.
        resp.on('end', () => {
          resolve(data.split('\n')); //  This
        });
      })
      .on('error', (err) => {
        reject(err);
      });
  });
};

(async (url) => {
  console.log(await getScript(url));
})(
  'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/monosans/proxy-list/main/proxies/http.txt'
);
```

Comment: Probably also worth showing that you can do `.filter(Boolean)` to remove any empty values: `data.split('\n').filter(Boolean)`

Comment: So when I try and use httpProxies outside of that function it says ReferenceError: httpProxies is not defined.

Is  there a way to define the array so it can be used throughout my program?

Comment: @RyanWheale These proxy lists are most of the time computer generated to disturbances are not really there. But yea we can do so to remove empty lines if they exist.

Comment: would you mind showing me how this would look? I've been playing around with it and cant quite figure it out. I know this is basic but I'm still very new to programming. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: @3jay1 You can do something like this: https://pastebin.com/2zC5PLkQ
When we don't have top-level await then its best to make a function and just write all the code inside there.